# Hide/Delete row when exporting html table with XLSX (table to sheet) in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, export-to-excel

I am trying to export selected data to excel. I am currently using XLSX 'table_to_sheet' method to achieve this purpose but it is exporting whole data instead of selected rows. Is there any way to filter records in table_to_sheet method so that only those records are exported which have 'checked' property 'true'?

Please find below code for better understanding

```
exportTableToExcel(TableElement: ElementRef, FileName: string, Extension: string) {
    const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.table_to_sheet(TableElement.nativeElement);
    const workbook: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workbook, ws, 'ClassDataExport');

    XLSX.writeFile(workbook, `${FileName}.${Extension}`);
  }
```

P.S: Is it achievable with json_to_sheet?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

This task has been done so no need assistance over this feature :)

Comment: Can you share how you solved?

Comment: eventually gave up, allowed users to create their excel output from firefox and if come from chrome then used a GET request and generated a smaller result from backend. Then loaded as usual through filesaver